# Start instances from specific subnet

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron

we have a network with two subnets (subnet1, subnet2).

However when instances are launched they receive IP only one from subnet1 (probably until it has no more IPs to offer)

Do you know the rule on which a subnet is selected, and how we can prioritize subnet2 or disable new IP allocations from subnet1?

Currently the best I can think of is creating a port in subnet1 and creating an instance with it.
However upon instance deletion the port is not cleared and overall I would prefer more general solution.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if that is what you're looking for, but you could clear the allocation pool from a subnet: `openstack subnet set --no-allocation-pool ...`. But this isn't a general solution, of course.

Comment: Wouldn't that affect instances that have ip allocations from that subnet?

Comment: I can't really answer that, haven't tried it. I assumed that running instances wouldn't notice, but a reboot would probably impact their ability to get an IP from the DHCP. So maybe it's not the best idea...